# How can I change the default behaviour of "Terminal: Explorer Kind" in VS Code Settings?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

By default, "Terminal: Explorer Kind" is set to "integrated" but even if I change it to external, nothing seems to change.

I want Windows CMD to open up externally when I build & debug a C++ program on VS Code.
For perspective, if I run a C++ program in CodeBlocks, I see the output on CMD that pops up. How do I achieve the same on VS Code?

Comment: What happens when you press `CTRL + SHIFT + C` (assuming windows)

Comment: @soulshined I have set it to Windows CMD so that opens up.

Comment: Okay, great, now just set the `console` attribute in your launch configuration to `external`

Comment: There isn't any `console` attribute in the launch.json file. Although, it has this `"externalConsole": false`. But, even though I set it to true and CMD does pop up, and it takes input for my CPP program but closes immediately before giving the output (for context, I am using VS Code for Competitive Coding and I need to see outputs after I am done with the inputs). Also, I tried what you recommended and what the link you provided suggested but still no luck.